# Merge rows duplicate values in a column using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have DataFrame like this

```
A   B   C   D
010  100 NaN 300
020  NaN 200 400
020  100 NaN NaN
030  NaN NaN  19
030   1  NaN  NaN
040   NaN 2    1
```

How can I merge all rows that have duplicate (same value) in Column `A` so that other values fill the empty places?

End result

```
A    B   C   D
010  100 NaN 300
020  100 200 400
030  1   NaN    19
040  NaN 2     1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with

```
df=df.groupby('A',as_index=False).first()
Out[65]: 
    A      B      C      D
0  10  100.0    NaN  300.0
1  20  100.0  200.0  400.0
2  30    1.0    NaN   19.0
3  40    NaN    2.0    1.0
```